# Bash Shell recursive folder

Tags: bash, shell, recursion

I want to go recursive through my folders and print the folders/files out.
This code should work but it only works for the first folder. Then its stop without a error.

```
#!/bin/bash

dateiDurchsuchen() {
    DATEIEN=($(ls -d $1/*))
    for(( i=0;i<${#DATEIEN[*]};i++ ))
    do 
        echo ${#DATEIEN[*]}
        ELEMENT=${DATEIEN[$i]}
        echo $ELEMENT
        if [ -d $ELEMENT ]
        then    
            dateiDurchsuchen $ELEMENT
        fi
    done
}
dateiDurchsuchen $HOME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because bash variables are global by default.

You have to explicitly mark them local:

```
dateiDurchsuchen() {
    local DATEIEN=( "$1"/* )
    local i
    for(( i=0;i<${#DATEIEN[@]};i++ ))
    do
        echo ${#DATEIEN[@]}
        local ELEMENT=${DATEIEN[$i]}
        echo "$ELEMENT"
        if [ -d "$ELEMENT" ]
        then
            dateiDurchsuchen "$ELEMENT"
        fi
    done
}
dateiDurchsuchen "$HOME"
```

Also note how the redundant `ls` is removed, and the variables quoted. This is required to handle filenames with special characters.

Comment: @Schs That was not the problem and your solution does not work. Create a `foo/bar/baz/myfile` in your home directory and you'll see that `myfile` doesn't get listed.

Comment: Yes sry you're right. It works with your solution. Thanks for your help. Can you say why ls is redundant, so I learn something...

Comment: @Schs globs are expanded by the shell, `ls -d` just lists the input with colors and in columns, neither of which is used here. You could just as well have used `array=( $(echo $1/*) )`, "print out every filename separated by spaces, capture that output, split it by spaces, and add each element to the array" which is better expressed as `array=( "$1"/* )` "put every filename into the array"

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

dateiDurchsuchen() {
    DATEIEN=($(ls $1/*))
    for(( i=0;i<${#DATEIEN[*]};i++ ))
    do 
        echo ${#DATEIEN[*]}
        ELEMENT=${DATEIEN[$i]}
        echo $ELEMENT
        if [ -d $ELEMENT ]
        then    
            dateiDurchsuchen $ELEMENT
        fi
    done
}
dateiDurchsuchen $HOME
```